# Why I am getting Time Limit Exceeded?

Tags: c++

I am getting Time Limit Exceeded on submitting this question

**Question:**

Let's consider a triangle of numbers in which a number appears in the first line, two numbers appear in the second line, three in the third line, etc. Develop a program which will compute the largest of the sums of numbers that appear on the paths starting from the top towards the base, so that:

on each path the next number is located on the row below, more precisely either 
directly below or below and one place to the right;

the number of rows is strictly positive, but less than 100

all numbers are positive integers between O and 99.

**My Code:**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    int trian(int i,int j);
    long long int n,a[100][100];
    int main()
    {
        long long int t,i,j,v,k;
        scanf("%lld",&t);
        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%lld",&n);
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<j+1;k++)
                {
                    scanf("%lld",&a[j][k]);
                }
            } 
            v=trian(0,0);
            printf("%lld\n",v);
        }
    }
    int trian(int i,int j)
    {
        if(i>=n)
        return 0;
        else
        return (a[i][j]+(std::max(trian(i+1,j),trian(i+1,j+1))));
    }
```

Comment: Please add the (minimal necessary) code (to reproduce your issue) as well as a description of the problem to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I am getting Time Limit Exceeded?

Consider this triangle (ignore the numbers):

```
1
2 3
```

There are 2 possible paths to take here. Let's add a row:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

The `4` can only be reached via a path that ends directly above, the `5` has two paths which can reach it, the `6` can only be reached from the path previously ending left above of it. We now have 4 possible paths. Another row:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 0
```

That's 8 possible paths. Do you see a pattern? Let's describe the path straight down to `7`, starting from `1`:

```
D = DOWN
R = DOWN AND RIGHT

DDD
```

The (single) path to `0`:

```
RRR
```

Since in each step you go down one row, you can only chose between the two possibilities `number of rows - 1` times, thus giving you:

```
2^(number of rows - 1) possible paths
```

With 100 rows, that's **alot**. Your code tries to compute each of these paths separately. Assuming computing 1 path takes 1 nanosecond (which would be blazing fast) computing them all would take more than `2 * 10^16` **years**. Well, ...

> Time Limit Exceeded

So you now know that you cannot just compute every possible path and take the maximum. The main issue is the following:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

One path to the `5` is `1 + 3 + 5`, the path to the `6` is `1 + 3 + 6`. Your code computes each path separately, thus `1 + 3` will be computed twice. If you save that result, you'll get rid of most of the unnecessary computations.

How could you store such results? Well, `1 + 3` is the computation of the path arriving at `3`, so store it there. What if a number (say `5`) can be reached by multiple paths?

`5` could be reached via `1 + 2 + 5` or `1 + 3 + 5`.

Any path going through the `5` will give a higher result if it wen't through the `3` first, so only remember this path (and ignore the path through the `2`, it's useless now).

So, as an algorithm:

For each row, starting at row 1 (not the first, but the second): For each entry: Calculate the maximum of the entries left above (if available) and directly above (if available) and store the result + the entry's value as new value for the entry. Then, find the maximum of the last row.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation @DanielJour